# Can I create a new folder/directory under Windows Certificates and import all my self signed CA certificates in it

Tags: windows, certificate, truststore

I am unable to find a solution where I can create a new folder/directory under Windows Certificates so that I can import all my self signed CA certificates into that folder.

I know that we can import our self signed CA certificates under Windows ROOT Trusted Root CA. But I have a requirement where we need to create a new Folder/Directory under the Windows Certificates so that I can import all of my self signed CA certificates under that folder. 
We have lot of self signed CA certificates and my project requirement states that they be grouped under one folder.
I opened the certmgr.msc and checked for options but I could not find the option to create a new directory under the Windows Certificates. Is it possible to achieve this requirement?

[image: New Folder needed]

Comment: If you're asking for how to do it with UI/CLI tools, Server Fault seems a more appropriate place.  If you are asking about API, you'd need to share more about your constraints/language/etc.

Comment: Any windows command or utility or API (any language) would be helpful. Requirement is to create a new folder under the Windows Certificates as shown in the image (Ex: MyProjectName folder similar to Personal or Trusted Root certification authorities) . I want to import ALL my project self signed CA certificates, issued end entity certificates (around 500 certificates in total) with their private keys, into this custom certificate folder so that we can maintain, Reissue on request again to end entities, revoke etc.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with PowerShell.

```
cd Cert:\
cd LocalMachine
mkdir somefolder
```

Comment: This works, but you need to remember to run PowerShell as Administrator or you'll an error that says "The system cannot find the file specified"

Answer (score 3):

If you’re working in C, [CertOpenStore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certopenstore), without the existing-only flag, will create a store.

In C# you can get the same by

```
X509Store store = new X509Store(storeName, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
// the store should now appear in MMC (after a refresh)
```

Adding to that store object works like any other store.

In my experience MMC won’t display private key management options for the custom store. Maybe there are options to let it do so, but any commandline utilities (or custom code) will probably see it just as any other store. (In MMC’s defense, it’s treating it like “any other store”... it thinks only the “My” store has private keys associated).